# TextView typeface changes to default after resuming app

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView which uses a custom Typeface and the problem I'm running into is that the Typeface changes to the default system typeface when android decides to close my app (while it's running in the background) and I start the app back up.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening? I've tried setting the typeface again in onResume, onStart, and onRestart methods yet the problem still occurs.

-UPDATE-

I've attached code. This is happening to the tView TextView.

-UPDATE 2-

I've fixed the problem. I moved the Typeface declaration to the class and on the onResume method I reinitialize the typeface and set the TextView typeface again. This prevents the TextView's typeface from going back to default.

```
public class TemperaturePage extends ActionBarActivity{

public static Spinner spinnerTo;
private static EditText text;

private TextView tView;

private AdView mAdView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.temperature_page);

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    spinnerTo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_convert_to);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text_box);

    celsiusOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celsius_output_text);
    fahrenheitOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fahrenheit_output_text);
    kelvinOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kelvin_output_text);

    Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.statusBarOrange));

    tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


    button.setTypeface(MainActivity.font2);
    button2.setTypeface(MainActivity.font2);

    tView.setTypeface(MainActivity.font);

    text.requestFocus();

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.temperature_units, R.layout.spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
    spinnerTo.setAdapter(adapter);

}

 @Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    tView.setTypeface(MainActivity.font);
}

@Override
public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    tView.setTypeface(MainActivity.font);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    tView.setTypeface(MainActivity.font);
    mAdView.resume();
}   

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mAdView.pause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mAdView.destroy();
}
```

Comment: What is `MainActivity.font` ?

Comment: I have the fonts declared in MainActivity so I don't have to recreate them in every class